# NSDictionary not populating in time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, mbprogresshud, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm implementing a username/password check by pinging the server for a JSON file, then checking it for the pair. My `userDictionary` isn't populating by the time I'm checking it. I'm assuming this is because `NSURLSession` is asynchronous and it's just not getting the data back by the time I need it. In my `ServerCommunicationModel`, I have:

```
- (void)getUserDictionaryFromServer
{
    NSString *userFileURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userFile.json", REMOTE_PATH_TO_ROOT_APP_FOLDER];
    NSURL    *userFileURL       = [NSURL URLWithString:userFileURLString];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *userFileTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:userFileURL
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                                     {
                                                         NSDictionary *returnJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                                                      error:nil];
                                                         self.userDictionary = [returnJSON objectForKey:@"users"];
                                                     }];

    [userFileTask resume];
}
```

Then in the view controller:

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    _usernameEntered = self.usernameTextField.text;
    _passwordEntered = self.passwordTextField.text;

    // Make sure the user put something in for a username and password
    if ([_usernameEntered isEqualToString:@""] || [_passwordEntered isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self showAlertViewWithText:@"" :@"Please enter a username and password" :@"OK"];
    }

    // Stow a spinner while checking credentials
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        // Get the user file from the server
        WAServerCommunicationModel *server = [WAServerCommunicationModel sharedInstance];
        [server getUserDictionaryFromServer];
        self.users = [server userDictionary];

        if ([self goodUser])
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginOK" sender:self];

        } else
        {
            [self showAlertViewWithText:@"" :@"Invalid Username or Password" :@"Try Again"];
        }

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `getUserDictionaryFromServer` method and add success/failure parameters like this:

```
- (void)getUserDictionaryFromServerWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary * userDictionary))success
                                       failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

Then, invoke the appropriate callback (success/failure) on getting the response from the server.

After doing so, if you invoke `[server userDictionary];` within the success block, it would always be populated correctly.

**Edit**:
NSURLSession provides an API with a completionHandler which might be useful. You can use it instead of delegation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data,
                                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                                    NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Comment: I edited it to include a completion handler (and changed the question). I'm still having an issue with it not being populated the first time I press the submit button. It is populated if I press the submit button again.

Comment: @WillLuce I don't see that you added success/failure blocks to getUserDictionaryFromServer method like I mentioned. After adding those, in your completionHandler block, you can invoke the success block if the error is nil.